# $(x^*+v)\cdot\nabla F(x^*+v)\geq 0$ for all $F$ if and only if $v$ is in the direction of $-e_1$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative

$x\in\mathbb R^2$

$F(x)$ is a two-dimensional concave function. $F(x)$ is strictly increasing in the direction of $x_2$.

$x^*$ is a point on $x_1$-axis such that the partial derivative $F_{x_1}(x^*)=0$.

$e_1$ is the vector direction of $x_1$-axis.

Can we prove the following:

> The derivative $(x^*+v)\cdot\nabla F(x^*+v)\geq 0$ for all $F$ if and only if $v$ is in the direction of $-e_1$?

---

I draw a plot in 2D and the result is very intuitive. If we move the $x^*$ a little bit along $-e_1$, to $x^*-v\epsilon$, then we must have:

$$F_{x_1}(x^*-\epsilon e_1)\geq 0$$

because $f$ is concave. But idk how to formally prove the whole thing without a graphic illustration. Maybe I'll try to pick a $v$ and try to construct a counterexample.